# Menu on mobile version doesn't collapse after choosing menu item

Tags: menus

I currently have a one page site. On the mobile version when the menu expands and i choose an item the menu stays open while the page moves to correct anchor but it is blocked by the menu. is there a code or snippet to insert to make the menu collapse after an item is selected?

Thanks

Comment: What specific plugin or theme is generating your menu? The answer will depend on how its coded.

Comment: @nateallen I'm using athlete theme wordpress theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this jQuery to your theme:

```
(function($) { 
    $('.nav-menu a').on('click', function(){
        if ( $(this).data('toggle') !== 'dropdown' ) {
            $('.main-menu .close-button').click();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

It will close the menu when a nav link is clicked.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! where exactly do i add it? @nateallen

Comment: Can you please advise where to insert this? Thank you!

Comment: Here's an article that talks about adding JavaScript to WordPress the right way: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-javascript-and-css-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins--wp-24321
but if that's too complicated,  you could use a plugin like this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-javascript-editor/

Comment: You're welcome! Thank you for accepting the answer. Let me know if you need anything else.